# Use Maven Jar plugin and Spring boot maven plugin simultaneously

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am trying to create jar for my spring boot server using spring boot maven plugin and my test automation framework jar from same project and pom file. To read external resources I am trying to defined manifest entries in maven jar plugin but this is causing spring server to not find application.properties in its default locations when run as a linux service using /etc/init.d/my-jar start.

Here is snippet of my pom file

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.3</version>
  <configuration>
    <descriptors>
      <descriptor>src/assembly/dep.xml</descriptor>
    </descriptors>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>com.myorg.mainclass</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-main-only</finalName>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>com.myorg.mainclass</mainClass>
      </manifest>
      <manifestEntries>
        <Class-Path>./config/</Class-Path>
      </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/application-test.properties</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>verify</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>test-jar</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I have tried changing phase of my maven assembly and jar plugin to verify but the problem still persists. Removing manifest entry seems to work but then my external resource files are not read.

Comment: First why are you using springloaded which is five years old.. second why do you try to add things in manifest to load an application.properties file? If you like to have external configuration that can be done in several ways:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config why do you use maven-assembly-plugin for an spring boot application?

Comment: @khmarbaise I need to separate test jars for running my E2E test during my CI/CD pipeline that is why I am using maven-spring-boot and assembly plugin.

Comment: I strongly recommend to use the spring-boot-maven-plugin by default. Use for example testcontainers to setup environment and write your E2E by using JUnit Jupiter ...You can start your own app via ProcessBuilder in an easy way. There no need to package separately which in the end does not test the real application...

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem I removed the manifest entries from maven jar plugin and then while running the test jar. I added the external resource directory path into classpath as follows:

```
java -classpath my/external/resource/directory/path -jar my-tests.jar
```